# Method Illuminate\Http\Request::date does not exist

Tags: laravel, date

I am new to Laravel, and i wanted to create CRUD application using this framework. But when everytime i submit i keep on getting this error 'Method Illuminate\Http\Request::date does not exist.' I can't store it to database.
[Full Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZm7d.png) [Full Form Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t149.png)

```
//blade template code
<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    {{Form::label('delivery_date', 'Delivery Date:')}}
    {{Form::date('delivery_date', \Carbon\Carbon::now())}}
</div>

// controller code
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Customer;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class CustomersController extends Controller
{
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'owner_name' => 'required',
        'store_name' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'latitude' => 'required',
        'longitude' => 'required',
        'cluster' => 'required'
    ]);

    // create customers
    $customer = new Customer;
    $customer->owner_name = $request->input('owner_name');
    $customer->store_name = $request->input('store_name');
    $customer->contact_no = $request->input('contact_no');
    $customer->address = $request->input('address');
    $customer->latitude = $request->input('latitude');
    $customer->longitude = $request->input('longitude');
    $customer->cluster = $request->input('cluster');
    $customer->delivery_date = $request->date('delivery_date');
    $customer->save();
    return redirect('/customers')->with('success', 'Customer Added!');
}
}
```

Comment: share controller code where you used `Request` ?

Comment: @C2486 done T_T

Comment: Share the full error message, too.

Comment: I cant paste it but i added a link of a picture that shows the whole error. Hope it can help T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no such thing as $request->date() so code should be

```
  $customer->delivery_date = $request->input('delivery_date');
```

or use Carbon if you want a date value

Comment: I'll try this when i got home :) thank you for your answer!

Comment: Well this is the one that solved the problem. :) Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The **Form::label** expression is not used any more. It was used in **Laravel 4**, and in **Laravel 5** there is a new standard to manage forms.

If you get this error, in the beginning of your controller you should add:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

And then the form HTML should be

```
<form action="{{ route('customers.store') }}" method="POST">
@csrf

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label for="delivery_date">Delivery Date</label>
        <input name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div></form>
```

Comment: So i dont have to use forms from laravel collective? @Davide Casiraghi

Comment: I mean, It's a way to keep using the old format in Laravel 5. But if you are new to laravel you should use the new standard

Comment: I added a link of a picture that shows my full form code. :3

Comment: If you post your code I can change it to make it works with the new standard

Comment: I mean the form code.. I cannot copy/paste it from the picture,. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 $customer->delivery_date = $request->delivery_date;
```